# Fine Tuning Pretrained Model MobileNet_V3_Large PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to add a layer to fine-tune the MobileNet_V3_Large pre-trained model. I looked around at the PyTorch docs but they don't have a tutorials for this specific pre-trained model. I did find that I can fine-tune MobileNet_V2 with:

```py
model_ft =models.mobilenet_v2(pretrained=True,progress=True)
    
model_ft.classifier[1] = nn.Linear(model_ft.last_channel, out_features=len(class_names))
```

but I am not sure what the linear layer for MobileNet V3 should look like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For V3 Large, you should do

```
model_ft = models.mobilenet_v3_large(pretrained=True, progress=True)
model_ft.classifier[-1] = nn.Linear(1280, your_number_of_classes)
```

(This would also work for V2, but the code you posted would not work for V3 correctly).

To see the structure of your network, you can just do

```
print(model_ft.classifier)
```

or

```
print(model_ft)
```

For fine-tuning people often (but not always) freeze all layers except the last one. Again, the layer to *not* freeze is `model_ft.classifier[-1]` rather than `model_ft.classifier[1]`.

Whether or not you should freeze layers depends on how much data you have, and is best determined empirically.

Comment: Hey , I've been trying to use mobile net v3 but it gives output below 0.
I wanted to know if you know which activation function this code block will make it use , and wether or not I should just map -1, 1 range to a 0, 1  one

Comment: @Mai Those are logits (Google them). If you need probabilities, you need to feed them to `softmax`.